# Correct implementation of the Filter (Criteria) Design Pattern

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, design-patterns, design-principles

The design pattern is explained here:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/filter_pattern.htm

I'm working on a software very similar to Adobe Lightroom or ACDSee but with different purposes. The user (photographer) is able to import thousands of images from his hard drive (it wouldn't be weird to have over 100k/200k images).

We have a side panel where users can create custom "filters" which are expressions like:

```
Does contain the keyword: "car"
AND
Does not contain the keyword "woods"
AND
(
Camera model is "Nikon D300s"
OR
Camera model is "Canon 7D Mark II"
)
AND
NOT
Directory is "C:\today_pictures"
```

You can get the idea from the above example.

We have a SQLite database where all image information is stored. The question is, should we load ALL Photo objects into memory from the database the first time the program is loaded and implement the Criteria/Filter design pattern as explained in the website cited above so our Criteria classes filter objects or is better to do the criteria classes actually generate an SQL query that is finally executed in order to retrieve only what's needed from the database?

We are developing the program with C++ (QT).

Comment: You are saying that the user usually has up to Nk items, with no upper limit for N. Why do you think that to load all of them from a db and then use a filter could be a preferable solution over a well defined query?

Comment: I suppose there can be a limit, maybe 500k...

Comment: No, I'm just asking if the normal thing is to load everything into memory or maybe I should use some kind of cache?  But my question actually comes from seeing the implementation of the Filter/Criteria pattern in the link I've provided... they inspect in memory objects in order to return the result set...  .

Comment: My background is of very low level programming, so this for me is not clear as to what's the best solution and I was hoping people could point out ideas and what a good solution could be for this implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**: It's already properly implemented in SQLITE3, and look at how long that took. You'll face the same burden.

It'd be a horrible case of data duplication to read the data from the database and store it again in another data structure. Use database queries to implement the query that the user gave you. Let the database execute the query. That's what databases are for.

By reimplementing a search/query system for ~500k records, you'll be rewriting large chunks of a bog-standard database yourself. It'd be a mostly pointless exercise. SQLITE3 is *very* well tested and is essentially foolproof. It'll cost you thousands of hours of work to reimplement even a small fraction of its capabilities *and* reliability/resiliency. If that doesn't scream "reinventing the wheel", I don't know what does.

The database also allows you to very easily implement lookahead/dropdowns to aid the user in writing the query. For example, as you're typing out "camera model is", the user can have an option of autocompletion or a dropdown to select one or more models from.

You paid the "price" of a database, it'd be a shame for it all to go to waste. So, use it. It'll give you lots of leverage, and allow you to implement features two orders of magnitude faster than otherwise.

The pattern you've linked to is just a pattern. It doesn't mean that it's an exact blueprint of how to design your application to perform on real data. You'll be, eventually, fighting things such as concurrency (a file scanning thread running to update the metadata), indexing, resiliency in face of crashes, etc. In the end you'll end up with big chunks of SQLITE reimplemented for your particular application. 500k metadata records are nothing much, if you design your query translator well and support it with proper indexes, it'll work perfectly well.